# Change Width Dynamically Select2

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

Hello I am using select2 plugin for drop down list. I am trying to set width to different value on open event but with no success. Is there any way to accomplish this in more convenient way ?

```
        $('#select').select2({
            width: o.width,
            data: objs // some data
        });

        $('$select').on('select2:open', function (e) {
            $(this).select2({width: 400}); // this does not work...
            // select2 is opened, handle event
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

> Try this may help you, you can add a css class and set width into css...

```js
 
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $("#ddl1").select2({dropdownCssClass : 'set_ddl_size'}); 
});
```

```css
#ddl1 {
    width: 100%;       
}

 .select2-drop-mask {
            width: 99%;
        }
         .set_ddl_size {
            width: 60% !important;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/select2/3.3.2/select2.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/select2/3.3.2/select2.js"></script>
<body>
    <select id="ddl1">
       <option value="small">Small</option>
       <option value="medium">Medium Medium</option>
       <option value="larg">Larg Larg Larg Larg</option>
       <option value="verylarge">verylarge verylarge verylarge verylarge </option>
    </select>
</body>
```